# How would I iterate through pokeAPI to get all subsequent pokemon data?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

Hi I'm using Vuejs to get some pokemon data. So I figured out how to retrieve all the pokemon name and their api urls to get more information about them. The issue is I don't know how to take those URLs and access each pokemon's specific data. I tried to increment a variable and concatenate it to the URL to get their data but it didn't work. I also tried to access the data from the api call I already but that also didn't work.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{subtitle}}</h2>
    <div v-for="pokemon in basicInfo" v-bind:key="pokemon.name">
  <span>{{ pokemon.name}}</span>
</div>
<!-- Nothing is produced, and I dont get I an error -->
<div v-for="pokemon2 in advInfo" v-bind:key="pokemon2.index">
  <span>{{pokemon2}}</span>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      subtitle: "First 150 pokemon",
      basicInfo: [],
      advInfo:[],
      i:0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // trying to increment i 
  getNext: function(){
    this.i=i++;
  }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
  // this gets a list of the first 20 pokemon. I can get the pokemon's name and their url
  .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")

  .then(response => {
    this.basicInfo = response.data.results;
  });

      // here I'm trying to access more specific data on each pokemon by concatenating a number to the url 
    axios
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5")

      .then(response => {
        this.advInfo= response.data.results;

      });

  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like ".../api/v2/pokemon/" produces an object with a results array, and those results contain uri's like ".../api/v2/pokemon/(some id)"

The way to combine them is as follows:

```
axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/").then(response => {
  this.basicInfo = response
  let promises = this.basicInfo.map(result => {
    return axios.get(result.url)
  })
  Promise.all(promises).then(response => {
    this.advInfo = response
  })
});
```

Now `advInfo` will be an array, like you expect so you can render it with v-for....

```
<div v-for="(pokemon2, i) in advInfo" :key="i">
  <pre>{{pokemon2}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: So I used the code you added, but now I get a "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error. I thought the I already declared basicInfo as an array earlier

Comment: That error implies that response.results is undefined.  Just looked again at the api - and there's no field called results.  See edit....